# Auditing Metadata for folders

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, folder, auditing, metadata

I am using Folders in Sharpeoint 2010 Foundation to create document sets as document sets are not supported in Foundation edition.

I have created a custom content type inherited from Folder, and I have added some metadata to my folder. Such as description, type and so on.

However, versioning is not applied to Folders. which means that if a user changed any field in the metadata of the the folder, I will not be able to see who changed what(or will I?)

I was just wondering whether there is any way to audit metadata of the folders in sharepoint or not. Have you come across such a problem before?

thanks for help in advance
regards

Comment: it looks like that it is not possible...

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764450/can-sharepoint-document-library-support-folder-versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic discussed on the thread below, it looks like that it is not possible.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764450/can-sharepoint-document-library-support-folder-versioning)